# How to style the <option> with only CSS?

Tags: css, html-select

### Note: This question is not about making a custom dropdown. It's only about possibilities of styling `<option>` elements within the select element in CSS

How can I style `<option>`s of a `<select>` element with cross-browser compatibility? I know many JavaScript ways which customize the dropdown to convert into `<li>`, which I'm not asking about.

```
<select class="select">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option >Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Yellow</option>
    <option>Brown</option>
</select>
```

I'm asking what could be possible with CSS only, with compatibility for IE9+, Firefox, and Chrome.

[image]

I want to style like this or as close as possible.

[image]

I tried here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/juwz3/3/, but Chrome doesn't show any styling except font color, while Firefox shows some more. How to get border and padding work in Chrome too?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**EDIT 2015 May**

Disclaimer: I've taken the snippet from the answer linked below:

### Important Update!

In addition to WebKit, as of [**Firefox 35**](http://jsfiddle.net/Etr4F/) we'll be able to use the `appearance` property:

> Using `-moz-appearance` with the `none` value on a combobox now remove the
>   dropdown button

So now in order to hide the default styling, it's as easy as adding the following rules on our select element:

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

For IE 11 support, you can use [`::-ms-expand`][15].

```
select::-ms-expand { /* for IE 11 */
    display: none;
}
```

**Old Answer**

Unfortunately what you ask is not possible by using pure CSS. However, here is something similar that you can choose as a work around. Check the live code below.

```css
div { 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 2px solid purple; 
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
div > ul { display: none; }
div:hover > ul {display: block; background: #f9f9f9; border-top: 1px solid purple;}
div:hover > ul > li { padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #4f4f4f;}
div:hover > ul > li:hover { background: white;}
div:hover > ul > li:hover > a { color: red; }
```

```html
<div>
  Select
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the question that you asked some time ago. 
[How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)
As it tells there, only in Chrome and to some extent in Firefox you can achieve what you want. Otherwise, unfortunately, there is no cross browser pure CSS solution for styling a select.

Comment: +1 thanks it's good code. but in my case i want to do with `<select>`. use of `<div>` is semantically not correct.

Comment: @JitendraVyas, I know, but as I replied, that's not possible. What you have achieved in the first picture is the most that you can do. See th edit. By the way, I replied your previous question as well, please see it.

Comment: The 'important update' part infers that you can style `option` tags with css, but you cannot, you can only style the `select` tag. Which is shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change/42087251#42087251)

Comment: Here's a JavaScript version of the above example that adds callback and some other useful features: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ergodropdown.htm

Answer (score 4):

There is no cross-browser way of styling option elements, certainly not to the extent of your second screenshot. You might be able to make them bold, and set the font-size, but that will be about it...

Answer (score 2):

I've played around with select items before and without overriding the functionality with JavaScript, I don't think it's possible in Chrome. Whether you use a plugin or write your own code, CSS only is a no go for Chrome/Safari and as you said, Firefox is better at dealing with it.