# javascript change select option background color drop down

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the background color to transparent on an HTML select option but it does not seem to change the color of the drop down menu. Does anyone know why?

READ ME: I only want to do it with JavaScript if possible.

```js
var Style2 = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for (var i = 0; i < Style2.length; i++) {
  Style2[i].style.borderRadius = '1em'; // standard
  Style2[i].style.MozBorderRadius = '1em'; // Mozilla
  Style2[i].style.WebkitBorderRadius = '1em'; // WebKitww
  Style2[i].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  Style2[i].style.border = "2px solid #000000";
  Style2[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff00";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}
```

```html
<select class="className">
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @DavidThomas That's the format for RGBA hex colors. You can read about it [in the draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation). While it is a draft, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari [all support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in javascript, you can do it in simply do it in css

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

option {
  color: green;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em
}
```

```html
<select class="className">
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `option` tag does not support rgba colors and transparency as well (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753020/6053654). As an alternative, you can simulate transparency giving the same `background-color` to the `option` tags:

```js
var Style2 = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for (var i = 0; i < Style2.length; i++) {
  Style2[i].style.borderRadius = '1em'; // standard
  Style2[i].style.MozBorderRadius = '1em'; // Mozilla
  Style2[i].style.WebkitBorderRadius = '1em'; // WebKitww
  Style2[i].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  Style2[i].style.border = "2px solid #000000";
  Style2[i].style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}
```

```html
<select class="className">
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
</select>
```

And you have one more way: you can use any configurable plugin, which simulates select/dropdown behavior, and as long as it isn't a `select` HTML element, the `background-color` should be configurable.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the option background to tranparent but you can change it to be the same as the body background color using computed style

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor
```

or use the select parent background color

```
window.getComputedStyle(Style2[0].parentElement).backgroundColor
```

```js
var Style2 = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for (var i = 0; i < Style2.length; i++) {
  Style2[i].style.borderRadius = '1em'; // standard
  Style2[i].style.MozBorderRadius = '1em'; // Mozilla
  Style2[i].style.WebkitBorderRadius = '1em'; // WebKitww
  Style2[i].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  Style2[i].style.border = "2px solid #000000";
  Style2[i].style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(Style2[0].parentElement).backgroundColor;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}
```

```html
<select class="className">
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
  <option value="link.html">text here</option>
</select>
```