# how to change color of dropdown option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

Any idea with this strange behaviour?
When you open dropdown and select for example 'Option 3' then click 'OPTION' button(it sets value to be 'Option 1'), then open dropdown and you can see that 'Option 3' is red but it shouldnt be red, now Option 1 should be red because its selected. Any idea ?

[image]

try the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-forked-5n1lpb?file=/src/material.js

code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  MenuItem,
  makeStyles,
  Select,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Box
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  select: {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    color: "white"
  },
  menuItem: {
    "& .Mui-selected": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
      color: "white"
    }
  }
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setValue("Option 1");
  };

  const data = [
    { value: "Option 1" },
    { value: "Option 2" },
    { value: "Option 3" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Box>
        <FormControl style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <Select
            // className={classes.select}
            MenuProps={{
              classes: {
                paper: classes.menuItem
              },

              anchorOrigin: {
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "left"
              },
              transformOrigin: {
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left"
              },
              getContentAnchorEl: null
            }}
            renderValue={() => <div>{value ? value : "Polygon"}</div>}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value="" style={{ marginTop: "1px" }}>
              <em>(No Selection)</em>
            </MenuItem>

            {data.map((option) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem className={classes.select} value={option.value}>
                  {option.value}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
          <Button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Option</Button>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can find answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752573/changing-the-background-color-of-a-drop-down-list-transparent-in-html)!

Comment: i want to change selected options background color

Answer (score 0):

`value` prop is missing for `Select`

```
<Select
  // ...
  value={value}
  // ...  
>
  {/* ... */}
</Select>
```

You can also change it like this:

```
<MenuItem
  style={{
    backgroundColor: value === option.value ? "red" : "magenta"
  }}
  value={option.value}
>
  {option.value}
</MenuItem>
);
```

Comment: i need to use renderValue, <div>{value ? value : "Polygon"}

Comment: You can still use it https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-forked-xesfgm

Comment: yes it works on codesandbox but in my real code when using both renderValue and value together then this wont work:     "& .Mui-selected": { backgroundColor: "red",
 }
  }

Comment: any other way to have that same functionality but without this  .Mui-selected ??