# How do I change the background color of the main cell of a html dropdown?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, html-select

To put it very simple, I want to change the background color of the *main field* (not sure what else to call it, it's the field marked in red in the example) of a HTML  element. I *do not* want to change the background color of the dropdown fields.

Is this possible? If so, how?

[image]

Source code:

```
<select>
   <option>Item 1</option>
   <option>Item 2</option>
   <option>Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This question already has answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753020/12904262

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the background color of a drop down list transparent in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752573/changing-the-background-color-of-a-drop-down-list-transparent-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to style de `select` and the `option`

```css
option{
  background-color: white;
}

select { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<select>
   <option value="3">tewe</option>
   <option value="8">eerer</option>
   <option value="5">ererere</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use css selectors: select and select option (I put red for options, but you can change color to whatever you like)

```css
select {
  background-color: yellow;
}
select option {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
   <option>Item 1</option>
   <option>Item 2</option>
   <option>Item 3</option>
</select>
```