# Modify select tag to inline display

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am just wondering how can I modify the css option from a select tag, to make them look like a bootstrap badge, something like this:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-badges
so every option is display inline?

Comment: Can you provide any HTML/CSS ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css

Comment: @ shalom Aleichem: not even close to be a similar question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot style `<option>` in the `<select>` tag. But you can use `<ul>` or `<nav>` instead.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/Etr4F/589/

Comment: Hi thanks, well the idea that I have is to be able to use it inside a form, this way when it is submitted I dont have to use any hidden inputs to submit the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

you can do position:absolute; or make a nav (HTML5) tag. Display inline-block is just one option.