# How to change the border-color of option?

Tags: css

I couldn't find anywhere to change the border on `<option>` but the background-color can be changed using `option{background-color: red;}` but `option{border: 1px solid red;}` won't work.

Using `option{border: 1px solid red;}` works in firefox but it's bordering each option but I wanted to border on whole option groups.

Is there any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial on styling options. http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/. And here an SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css

Comment: The question title refers to options, the text says you don’t want borders for options but for option groups. Please specify, by editing the question, or by closing this an posting a new one, which one you mean. Also provide a a real example, HTML and CSS, showing what you have tried and how the result differs from the expected/desired (and on which browser[s] this happens).

Comment: I've updated with picture. And I don't have optgroup. I've only options. Should I use optgroup?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with following piece of code:

```
<div id ="newdiv"><select id="mysel">
<optgroup><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option></optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

Used following css to provide border:

```
#mysel optgroup{  
 border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

It works as you wish in mozilla firefox.

Comment: this is not working