# Is there a way to make spacing or margin with CSS between <option> tags in a <select> form?

Tags: html, css

I have a form with around 8 options. I succeeded to make them diferent colors but now I would like to add white spacing between them - like 10px. I tried even adding border but its not showing. 
this is what Im trying

```
#mobileMenuSections select option {
    margin:5px 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#fff;
    background: url("Images/buttonnavy.png") no-repeat scroll left top #092F46;
}
```

or with border:

```
#mobileMenuSections select option {
    border-top:10px 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#fff;
    background: url("Images/buttonnavy.png") no-repeat scroll left top #092F46;
}
```

Unfortunately none of these are showing. Background image is also not showing.

thanks in advance for help.

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UCn4V/

Comment: I tried this... its not working padding is working but margin is not

Answer (score 0):

Styling options are very limited and very hard to maintain on differect browsers. I suggest you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css) stackoverflow question or maybe look into some jQuery UI dropdown list or another jQuery plugin.