# How to style the disabled and selected 'option' of a 'select' in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to use the first 'option' of a 'select' tag as a prompt to the user that input is required. So, I'd like the 'select' box to render the selection in a different color if the selected option is disabled.

So given the following code:

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose best player...</option>
  <option>Walter Payton</option>
  <option>Jim McMahon</option>
  <option>Mike Singletary</option>
  <option>Richard Dent</option>
  <option>Steve McMichael</option>
  <option>Wilber Marshall</option>
</select>
```

I'd like the page to show the dropdown with "Choose best player..." in the color gray and then change the color if a non-disabled option is chosen.

I'd prefer a css solution if it exists, but after googling for quite some time I'm beginning to be convinced that some JavaScript will be required. Any simple solutions out there?

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/bsegraves/pen/cDnmx) with this preloaded.

Comment: seems similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder?rq=1

Comment: Styling the `option` tag is not well supported. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css, makesure to read the questions linked there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a little javascript:

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="highlight(this)">
    <option class="invalid" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose best player...</option>
    <option>Walter Payton</option>
    <option>Jim McMahon</option>
    <option>Mike Singletary</option>
    <option>Richard Dent</option>
    <option>Steve McMichael</option>
    <option>Wilber Marshall</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
option.invalid {
    background: #eee;
}

option.valid {
    background: #ff8;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function highlight(field){
    field.options[0].className = 'valid';
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3oyu09/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (at least on the Mac using Chrome or Safari). :(

Comment: Yep, looks like a little javascript is required. Your updated answer sent me in the right direction. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/bsegraves/pen/vLsrC) that shows what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Pure css you want:

```
select option[disabled="disabled"][selected="selected"]
{text-decoration:underline;}
```

This will style an option with both disabled and selected set. However, beware of browser compatability issues.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kxlLI)

It won't however remove the style when another option is selected. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) `option:checked` should be able to be used, but I have not been able to get it to work reliably (http://jsfiddle.net/gb35e6yj/).

Answer (score 0):

I think your difficulty (with a pure css solution) will be targeting your select element based on the attributes of a child element.

I would use some javascript to check that selected item isn't disabled and then apply your css.