# How to change HTML5 datalist background color for the displayed options

Tags: javascript, css

I am using datalist for my Application .

On click of the Arrow its displaying 3 values (Crust1 , Crust2 and Crust3 )

Could you please tell me how can i change the background color for the displayed values

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/77/

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return RestrictVarchar(this,event,15);" id="topcrust-0" list="crustlist" class="crust" placeholder="Add Crust">
<datalist id="crustlist" "="">
<option>Crust1</option>
<option>Crust2</option>
<option>Crust3</option>
</datalist>

<input type="hidden" id="topcrustid-0" value="">
```

Comment: background color for the dropdown menu items? your question isn't really clear

Comment: `<datalist id="crustlist" "="">` Isn't there a problem with quotes at the end ?

Comment: yes i need to change the background color for the displayed items

Comment: updated code this link.   http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/78/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no way to style the `<option>` tag.

If you really want to achieve this, you will have to build a 'hack' and simulate a dropdown without using `<select>` tag.

See here : [How to style the <option> with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css)