# Have a equal row height in a dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a dropdown list. Each row is in a different font type. Now the problem is that each row height is different due to the different font type.

My question is that how do I extend the height so each row has a equal height in my drop down list?

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

```
  <select class="fonts">
     <option style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'">Comic Sans MS</option>
     <option style="font-family: Arial">Arial</option>
     <option style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'">Times New Roman</option>
  </select>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a quick [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwp9jo07/) - I'm testing in IE

Comment: Shows your code, Beki

Comment: Can you plz show code or live url.

Comment: you can use below css to set min height of option.
.parentclass option {
   min-height: 20px;
}

Comment: @MukeshPanchal thanks. `min-height: 100px;` didn't work. See my edit. I've created a quick Fiddle.

Comment: Styling options is not possible, you need to have a different HTML markup or use a JS plugin. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8431078/4711865

Comment: Yes @odedta is right. select option not take any style because it render depend on browser and OS which we use different browser and OS have different style.

Answer (score 0):

use something like:

```
option {
   padding: 30px 10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I did what you've suggested but no luck `.fonts  option{ padding: 30px 10px; }`

Comment: I see, it works for firefox, but it doesn't in chrome or other webkit browser...
https://jsfiddle.net/mq46c1ao/