# select with 300+ options looses styles on Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome

When you place a  tag with more than 300  tags in it, chrome displays it without any style.

To reproduce you have to create a php file (or html file) and have:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    select.green_select {
      color: green;
      font-size: 8pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>SELECT PROBLEM</h1>
  <?php
    print '<select class="green_select">'."\n";

    for ($i = 1; $i < 301; $i++) {
      print '<option value="'.$i.'">this should be green '.$i.'</option>'."\n";
    }

    print '</select>';

    print '<select class="green_select">'."\n";

    for ($i = 1; $i < 302; $i++) {
      print '<option value="'.$i.'">this should be green '.$i.'</option>'."\n";
    }

    print '</select>';
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The resulting html displays the first select drop-down with all options in green and with the correct font size, while the second one removes all styles.

[image: This select has 300 entries]

[image: This select has 301 entries]

This only happens on chrome, does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style the <option> with only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css)

Comment: hum, no, this is a chrome issue, see my answer below. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems it is a chrome issue.
See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339

I will have to wait for the next version of chrome.
Problem is on version 44.

Great. :)