# Underline a boostrap select option

Tags: css, angular

Working on an Angular project, using a select to edit CSS class of an object. All this is working fine but I would like to use the CSS class in the select input display.

Here's my code. I'm using css classes to define the properties.

```css
.boldunderline {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm" [(ngModel)]="miseenpage.titredecoration" id="titredecoration" name="titredecoration">
  <option value="0">Par défaut</option>
  <option value="underline" class="underline" mat-input-element>Souligné</option>
  <option value="italic" class="italic">Italique</option>
  <option value="bold" class="bold">Gras</option>
  <option value="bolditalic" class="bolditalic">Gras et italique</option>
  <option value="underlineitalic" class="underlineitalic">Souligné et italique</option>
  <option value="boldunderline" class="boldunderline">Gras et souligné</option>
    <option value="boldunderlineitalic" class="boldunderlineitalic" >Gras, italique et souligné</option>
</select>
```

It's working for bold and italic but not for underlining.
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You want to underline the all option of select ?

Comment: Only option 2, 7 and 8 wich are supposed get the text-decoration : underline

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208814/6845316 :please check this. Now we can achieve this by 2 methods only, one by using plugin as mentioned in this link or by pasting the option text as it is in option tag like :  `<option>t̲e̲s̲t̲ </option>`. So whatever you will paste it will show that way in web.

FOR PLUGIN METHOD: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260048/6845316

Both are workaround and typically for high level project ***NOT RECOMMENDED***

NOTE: ***NOT RECOMMENDED FOR MAJOR PROJECTS***

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since it's a little project I wonder if it's worth it. Will try it someday.