# How to apply css styles for select control options in chrome

Tags: html, css

I've a select box with some options, I need to apply styles specific to select control option.

Styles I want apply are :

```
color: #333333;
font-size: 14px;
min-height: 2em;
padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
margin-top: 0.125em;
cursor: pointer;
```

I've given class `.taskpanel-select-control` to my select control, 
and added css

```
.taskpanel-select-control option{
color: #333333;
font-size: 14px;
min-height: 2em;
padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
margin-top: 0.125em;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Css for my select control is:
border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid #757575;-webkit-appearance:none; -moz-appearance:none; appearance: none; background: url(images/caret_down.svg) no-repeat;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:1em;background-position: 96%;min-width: 5em;height: 1.75em;padding-left: 0.5em;padding-right: 2em;

But these are not respected in the select options, is there any way to make this happen.

[Image of Select Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAP6Z.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the <option> with only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css)

Comment: Can only be done with jquery. Look on google for jquery select option styling plugins.

Comment: I've used -webkit-appearance:none; -moz-appearance:none; appearance: none; styles for my select control, even I'm facing this problem

Comment: @SergeyDenisov, this problem I'm facing only in chrome, it is working in firefox.

Comment: I've used bootstrap dropdown to solve this issue, I'm almost out of my issue, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out solution for this issue.
Applying css styles for select options is not possible in chrome, where as it is possible in firefox.

To make it work in both firefox and chrome I constructed select or drop down using ul and li.

Through which I could able to apply whatever styles I wanted to my select options which are nothing but list items (li).

Found one issue with this approach, auto suggestion are not coming in my constructed drop down where as it is by default behavior of normal html select box.

Answer (score -1):

It should be as straightforward to apply styles to your `<options>` as to any other element:

```css
.taskpanel-select-control option {
color: #333333;
font-size: 14px;
min-height: 2em;
padding: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
margin-top: 0.125em;
cursor: pointer;
}

p {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>&lt;select&gt; containing unstyled &lt;option&gt; elements:</p>

<select>
<option>Registration</option> 
<option>Completion</option> 
<option>State</option> 
<option>Archive</option>
</select>

<p>&lt;select&gt; containing styled &lt;option&gt; elements:</p>

<select class="taskpanel-select-control">
<option>Registration</option> 
<option>Completion</option> 
<option>State</option> 
<option>Archive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I couldn't find any difference for the unstyled select box and styled select with this approach.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 43.0.4 and all the styles are displaying properly. What browser are you using?

Comment: I've verified in firefox, my styes are working fine, getting issue in chrome browser .I'm using chrome 46

Comment: Yep. I just tested it in chrome 47 - you're right, the chrome browser is not picking up the style declarations.

Comment: can I have any other alternative to make this happen

Comment: I've used bootstrap dropdown to solve this issue, I'm almost out of my issue, thanks for your help.

Comment: your suggested approach doesn't work in chrome that is what my issue, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: issue is in the chrome as the title says "How to apply css styles for select control options in chrome"