# Bootstrap class not applied in HTML select tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Getting puzzled why Bootstrap class `text-uppercase` is not working with select options in HTML, whereas apart from select option all classes are working fine.

Here is a working demo for `text-uppercase` :

http://plnkr.co/edit/DR8jPACODGzvW8W0ZX2u?p=preview

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>One</option>
    <option><span  class="text-uppercase">two</span></option> //class="text-uppercase" not working
    <option class="text-uppercase"> three</option> //same here
</select>
```

Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: you can't do that.... you need to add the class on the option.

Comment: Could you not add **.text-uppercase{text-transform:uppercase}** to your css?

Comment: because by default `button, select {    text-transform: none;}` is set somewhere overwrite it by `uppercase` you will get your output

Comment: Mny browsers doesnt allow selct/option styling. Some workarounds with examples are in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8431078/1368752)

Comment: but why ? we have predefined class already then why new one ? @ShiguriAnemone'

Comment: no i did't add but why i have to add this class @DanWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes exactly as said by @debin in comment. class `text-uppercase` is get overwritten by the default behaviour of bootstrap style i.e

```
button, select { text-transform: none;}
```

you can check it here...

> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css

so to apply the class like `text-uppercase` `text-capetalize` etc we have to add extra class in the css file or something like that i.e inline enternal or external style.
so exact answer is like this:

```
<select class="form-control customClass">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>two</option> 
    <option> three</option> 
</select>
```

use `.customClass` in your css and use style `text-transform: uppercase;`

second method as suggested by @SaucedApples

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>One</option>
    <option class="text-uppercase"><span>two</span></option>
    <option class="text-uppercase"> three</option> //same here
</select>
```

this will add indvidualy class to option tag.

posting it as answer may it help someone Else :)

Answer (score 3):

The `class="text-uppercase"` needs to be used with the `option` tag.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>One</option>
    <option class="text-uppercase"><span>two</span></option>
    <option class="text-uppercase"> three</option> //same here
</select>
```

You had been using `class="text-uppercase"` with `<span>` not `<option>`

Comment: me too used `text-uppercase` with option tag as in plnkr ! but why to add external css class in the css file ?

Comment: Because the existing class `text-uppercase` will be defined by he option tag and only usable with the option tag.  EG: 

`option .text-uppercase{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}`

Comment: i have used with `option` tag too check my last `option` tag so ?

Comment: see my updated plnkr your code is also not working !

Comment: Side note, stop using exclamation marks.  Makes me want to tell you to solve it yourself.

Comment: @PardeepJain I added the `text-uppercase` to only the second option.  Now the second option is uppercase as desired.  It's working as suggested by the upvotes on my answer.

Comment: this one also not working as you can see this in the plnkr. well thanx for the answer :)

Comment: hey @saucedApples sorry for everything its working now in windows. but before now i am working on linux and on ubuntu its not working dont know why. sorry for inconvenience. and thanx for answer :)

Comment: @pardeep jain no worries. Please upvote and mark as answered if it helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102922/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-saucedapples).