# How to apply changes to "select" option using CSS

Tags: css, html, select, html-select

Here's a sample of what it should look like : [Select box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHxyn.png)

I get country names from a database and generate dynamic options on page. Right now, i am showing the Html code (Not the database code). I tried lots of links to change the design (CSS), but none of them work on "select". I want to be able to change `padding , border, background-color, color` or `border-color`. Can i apply modifications to all those, for "select", using `css` or not ?

I also want to only show the first 5 options (first 5 country names) in the dropdown list when the button is clicked, using a `scrollbar`.

```css
#country option:first-child {
    display: none;
}

#country {
    float: left;
    width: 96%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #00BCEA;
    padding: 9px 5px;
    width: 93%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #00BCEA;
}
```

```html
<select id="country">
    <option value="selectOption">Select your country</option>
    <option value="selectOption1">Select your country1</option>
    <option value="selectOption2">Select your country2</option>
    <option value="selectOption3">Select your country3</option>
    <option value="selectOption4">Select your country4</option>
    <option value="selectOption5">Select your country5</option>
    <option value="selectOption6">Select your country6</option>
    <option value="selectOption7">Select your country7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's Okay, just you have an extra space after your ID! - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czhybqyn/)

Comment: this 'css' work i need more 'css' for option not for select

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css

Comment: I can't use except select option. this is my requirements.

Comment: Are you asking "Can I apply `padding` and `border` styles to `option` in CSS"?

Comment: @light yes, you are right.

Comment: Take a look at the answer @GermanoPlebani provided above. It may provide some insights to your query. As far as I know, only Firefox allows *some* CSS on options. The other browsers ignore most CSS rules on option.

Comment: It means `css` not working.

Comment: You also asked "I also want to fixed only 5 option in drop down box". Do you mean you only want to show the first 5 options? Or the last 5? Or you only want to retrieve 5 options from DB?

Comment: I want show only 5 option box. You can see in image more than 10 option show.

Comment: I know you want to show only 5. But which 5? Option 1,2,3,4,5? Option 2693, 2694, 2695, 2696, 2697? And what happens if your DB gives you 4,437 options? Which 5 do you want?

Comment: first 5 show in list after that show using scrollbar

Comment: All these information you're providing in the comments should be in your question.

Comment: This jquery plugin https://select2.github.io/ maybe can help you.