# Padding not working for SELECT OPTION in IE11

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-select

~I have created listbox control and trying to add padding between options, It is working with chrome but not working with IE11, Anyone can suggest what I am doing wrong.I need to place items in the listbox with line spacing.
     Below code contains style sheet I am using and HTML code which has select options tag, Tried styles with padding, margin, line space etc but no luck.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>change demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  
  
<style type="text/css">
    select::-ms-expand { /* for IE 11 */
      display: none;
    }

    .ListBox {  
        background-color: transparent;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
  vertical-align:middle;  
    }
 
 .ListBox option
 {
  padding:30px 30px 30px 30px;  

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
 }
}
}
 
</style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<select name="sweets" multiple="multiple" class="ListBox">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<div></div>
 
<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .change();
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try margins or width and height instead, styling options is not very well supported across browsers

Comment: margin , width height nothing helped me

Comment: option {display:block;} and then try various options

Comment: Ok will try and update

Comment: option{display:block} not making difference

Comment: does line-height work? Or border:30px solid White; ?

Comment: No, both are not working. I tried both.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this

```
select::-ms-expand { /* for IE 11 */
    display: none;
}
```

here:

[How to style the <option> with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css)

Comment: <style type="text/css">
 select{  
        background-color: transparent;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
  vertical-align:middle;  
    }
 
 select::-ms-expand
 {
  display:none;
 }
 
 select option
 { 
  padding:30px 30px 30px 30px;  
  line-height:30px; 
  border:30px solid white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
 }
}
}
 
</style>

Comment: :) may be... but I have to make it look pretty. Please help.