# HTML/CSS: floating option tags inside select tag

Tags: html, css

Look at this simple fiddle with floating `option`s inside a `select`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2adnvtut/1/)

this seems to work perfectly in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox. Is there any possibility or hack in order to achieve the same result in Firefox?

```
    <select size="8">
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option class="flip"></option>
      <option class="flip"></option>
      <option class="flip"></option>
      <option class="flip"></option>
    </select>

    select{
      width: 420px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    option{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
    }

    select option:nth-child(odd){
      background: #aaa;
    }
    select .flip:nth-child(odd){
      background: #fff;
    }
    select .flip:nth-child(even){
      background: #aaa;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should use radio buttons to solve your problem, as they are supported in every browser and you can order them and move them however you wish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select , http://stackoverflow.com/a/17203491/2008111 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css

Comment: Why try to use an element in a way that it's not meant to be used when there are better options more suited for this?

Comment: You can only use the select element in this case?

Answer (score 3):

For advanced styling with a select tag I recommend to use a workaround. Because:

> The `<select>` element is considered an "ugly" widget because it's impossible to style it consistently cross platform.

Source: [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare)

---

**A simple workaround example:**

```js
$('.dropdown-field').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.children('ul').slideToggle(100);
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.is('li')) {
    $this.children('span').html($target.text());
    $this.find('input[type="hidden"]').val($target.attr('data-value'));
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-field {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-field > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown-field > ul li {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
.dropdown-field > ul li:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-field">
  <span>please select ...</span>
  <ul>
    <li data-value="1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="2">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="3">Option 3</li>
    <li data-value="4">Option 4</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="myfield" value="">
</div>
```

Of course you have to adjust this to your requirements. But now you can style it as you wish (cross platform).