# How to change select box created by <select>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure how to edit the selection box created by `<select class="form-control">`, here's what I have:

```
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>00:00</option>
    <option>01:00</option>
  </select>
```

and my css:

```
.form-control {
  width: 60px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

this gives me:

[image]

but now how do I modify the actual box created by this select element? I want to get rid of that ugly yellow color, smooth the borders ... etc.. etc..

fiddle of the code above: https://jsfiddle.net/08zrLjgc/

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8430279

Comment: I've already seen both of those answers, and they do not answer this question. They both talk about replacing the arrow, but not how to specifically edit the border color of the box created.

Comment: There are a total of 33 answers provided in those two posts. They do not all focus on the drop-down arrow.

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html