# HTML Option menu border override without making custom element?

Tags: html, css

What are the css selectors used to style the border of the option menus like shown here. I want to override the default styles and not make a custom menu by hiding the default one like how its is done here [How to style the <option> with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css).

[image: 1]

I am trying to change the border color. and styling the option tags like this doesn't do it

```
option {
    border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: post the code that you are trying

Comment: This might be helpful, [How to style the option of a html select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select).