# How to edit the size of a box that pops up in with css?

Tags: html, css, popup

A box of codes of phone number of different countries pops up. As you can see there is some space left in table and my question is how to change the size of this table to make is smaller in. I tried in CSS "optgroup[label="Countries"]
{ width: height: }" but still it does not work. But when I change the color of background, is works. Can you please help me. Thank you in advance.

```html
 <select name="countryCode" id="countryCode">
 <optgroup label="Countries">
 <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44" Selected>UK (+44)</option>
 <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option>
<option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
<option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
<option data-countryCode="AO" value="244">Angola (+244)</option>
<option data-countryCode="CF" value="236">Central African Republic (+236)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the <option> with only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css)

Comment: I think `<optgroup>` is relative in size to `<select>` so to change it's width, you'd have to change `<select>`'s width. Not sure about height, however.

Comment: I tried to change the width of <select> but it changed only the border with UK(+44). The box with country calling codes that appears after clicking the arrow did not change in size.

Answer (score 0):

If you target the width of select#countryCode, width changes for me even on the popup. It just can't be smaller than the space required by the largest word/words in the dropdown.