# styling the dropdown portion of a select-option

Tags: html, css

simple question, if I have a select-option structure like this:

```
<select class="productIDSelector" id="productID" name="productID" [(ngModel)]="productId">
      <option *ngFor="let item of products" [value]="item.productID" class="optionList">
        <p class="idList"> {{ item.productID }}: </p>
        <p class="descList"> {{item.description}} </p>
      </option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to style the dropdown and it's components?

I can change the input-field to my liking, but I'd like the listed options to be styled as well and if possible have the dropdown open downward (it's a lot of data, so it always opens upwards).

Would that be possible? Preferably with html/css only.

---

Edit: As this was marked as dublicate:

I flew over the linked question (lots to read) and from what it felt like to me, it was aimed at styling mostly the input-box part of the select-dropdown.

To avoid any possible misunderstandings:

[image]

If I misunderstood the linked question or missed the important part in it, feel free to point it out to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: I might be wrong, but that question seemed to mostly focus on the input box of the select, not the dropdown part.

Comment: Here is perhaps a more relevant duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css. The TLDR there is that there isn't a way to do it.

Comment: So it's either javascript or nothing?