# AngularJS with a styled select drop down

Tags: css, angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.x app that I need to add a styled drop down as see in the image below. Some items need to have a red or green left border.
How can I achieve this?

[image: Drop down]

Comment: What code have you tried? It is hard to help answer a question like this without more information. Please add in the code you are using and what specifically about it does not work.

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css).

Answer (score 0):

Some more code would help.. but something like this

```
.element.red {
    border-left: 5px solid red;
}
.element.green {
    border-left: 5px solid green
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work on an HTML <option>