# Change style of selectmenu items (CSS)

Tags: html, css, sass

I have select. I it I have some of items.

I need to change style of it

Here is html of this select

```
 <ul class="facilities hide-small">
     <li class="airline">
         <select name="search[airline]" id="search_airline" class="custom">
            <option value="">Alla</option>
            <option value="SK">SAS</option>
            <option value="DY">Norwegian</option>
            <option value="EI">Aer Lingus</option>
            <option value="SU">Aeroflot</option>
            <option value="AR">Aerolineas Argentinas</option>
            <option value="AM">Aeromexico</option>
            <option value="BT">Air Baltic</option>
            <option value="AC">Air Canada</option>
            <option value="CA">Air China</option>
            <option value="UX">Air Europa</option>
            <option value="AF">Air France</option>
            <option value="AI">Air India</option>
            <option value="NZ">Air New Zealand</option>
</select>
            </li>
```

I need to change style of options, so I wrote this in css.

```
#search_airline.ui-menu-item-wrapper{
  background: #e4e4e4;
  color: #2311b2;
  font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

But it not works

If i wrote like this

```
.ui-menu-item-wrapper{
  background: #e4e4e4;
  color: #2311b2;
  font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

All works great

Here is screenshot

[image]

where is my problem can be?

Comment: You do — not — close the `<select></select>`.

Comment: I closed it. Updated my post@AjAX.

Comment: You want to put it before the `</li>`.

Comment: Anyway not works@AjAX.

Comment: _"But it not works, where is my problem can be?"_ - the first problem is that you are not giving us a proper problem description - so please go read [ask]. Describe _what exactly_ "doesn't work". Secondly, if this is about specific styles like the borders and their radius - browsers don't let you apply just any kind of styling to native input fields, you are very limited in what you can do with them. If you prior research on the topic did not turn up _that_ information, then I question if you have actually done any - this is a topic that has been discussed broadly already.

Comment: Use this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css

Comment: As the answers say, you can't style the ```<option>``` tag because it is not rendered like other elements. CSS has no control in it.

Comment: I edited question @D.Pardal

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the style of `<option>` via css, as it is rendered by user's OS not HTML.

Comment: I edited question

Answer (score 1):

You can't style `option` field. Because it have cross browser issue. Instead of you can use [Select2](https://select2.org/).

Comment: I edited question